# Unilateral OneToMany with Composite Key that is also a Foreign Key, should use @IdClass or @Embeddable?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, composite-primary-key, composite-key

I'm having difficulty deciding between using @IdClass or @Embeddable to model composite primary key for the OneToMany db relationship shown below.

[image: relationship table]

`user_id` is the primary key of the `user` table, and `user_merchant` uses both `merchant_id` and `user_id` as its composite key. A user can deal with several merchants and vice versa. The `user_merchant` table keeps track of the relationships between users and merchants.

Since '`user`' are the only ones who needs to know about its relationships, not the merchants, I'm going to model it as unidirectional One-To-Many relationship.

In the User entity, I'm hoping to model it like so:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User extends Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private Long userId;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private Set<Merchant> merchants;

}
```

For the Merchant entity, it's a bit tricky.

```
public class Merchant implements Serializable{

    @Column
    private String merchantId;

    .....

}
```

Running this piece of code will fail if @Id is not specify in `Merchant` class. I am not sure if I should use @IdClass or @Embedded/@Embeddable in this case, and what is the benefit of one over the other.

Can I avoid introducing a new User object in Merchant class like what most solutions show? Since merchants don't really need to know about user.

```
@Id
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "location_id")
private User user;
```

And how can I populate this field with when `User` object gets saved for the first time? If possible, I don't think I need another user reference inside of a merchant object that is already an attribute of the same user object.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Start here https://vladmihalcea.com/tutorials/hibernate/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I solved this problem:

I have identified this relationship to be a case of Unilateral One-To-Many relationship between parent and child objects, where child's composite primary key is partly made up of a foreign key from parent.

In the end, I chose to use `@IdClass` because I still need to access merchantId and it seems like the easiest way to do it.

The only change I made in User Class was removing `@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")` and replacing it with `mappedBy = "user"` in @OneToMany. Without this change, persisting this entity for the first time works just fine, but when I try updating this entity while removing a merchant from the set, it was giving me some errors.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User extends Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private Long userId;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, 
               mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Merchant> merchants;

    @PrePersist
    public void prePersistUser() {
        if (this.merchants != null) {
            this.merchants.forEach(merchant-> {
            merchant.setUser(this);
            });
        }
    }

}
```

As for the merchant class, I linked `MerchantPK.class` to Merchant.java via @IdClass.

I also made sure `insertable` and  `updatable = false` inside @JoinColumn,  since this relationship is unilateral and should only be insertable/updatable only from parent's side (User).

```
@Entity
@IdClass(MerchantPK.class)
@Table(name = "user_merchant")
public class Merchant {

    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String merchantId;


    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private UserEntity user;

}
```

In case of Unilateral One-To-Many relationship, only 1 @JoinColumn is needed which, in this case, is wherever the @ManyToOne is. The object with @OneToMany will still be the owner of the relationship, even when using mappedBy, since we specified `insertable = false` and `updatable = false`.